# Text in two columns with empty lines

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

How can I have text spread out evenly in two columns, if I need to allow empty lines for spacing?

I have come this far, but this will leave the empty line on the top of the first column if it happens to land there (I tried to reproduce that, but depends on your screen width).

So this is close, but not quite perfect yet:

```css
p {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This line is just stopped with a br.<br>
  This line is very long.............. ........... ............ ....... ....... ....
  <br>
  <br> 
  And I want a blank line before this one.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `p` tags instead of `br`, you can add a class to the empty lines and apply `break-before: avoid;` to that. That way, there will be no column break (which is affected as well as page breaks by this setting) before any element with that class:

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  display: block;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.empty {
  break-before: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This line is just stopped with a br.</p>
  <p>This line is very long.  This line is very long. </p>
  <p class="empty"></p>
  <p class="empty"></p>
  <p>And I want a blank line before this one.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, with some caveats: I had to move my text also to be inside <p> tags (which is probably correct anyway). Also, the empty <p></p> were not keeping an empty line, I put a &nbsp inside.
Columns still do not balance properly sometimes, at least apparently there are situations where one line would be better on the other col, but good enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  width:70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.left {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.right {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.top {
  width:100%;
}

.middle {
  width:100%;
}

.bottom {
  width:100%;
  padding-top:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top">Top left Top left Top left</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... Middle left very long... </div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom left Bottom left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">Top right Top right Top right</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... Middle right very long... </div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom right Bottom right Bottom right </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funny, this is displaying single column for me.
But even if the column part worked, this wouldn't balance the columns, would it? I mean, if left happened to be way longer, one side would be much longer, no?

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure what you want your end result to look like, but i am willing to bet a table would work best.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This line is just stopped with a br.</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This line is very long.............. .... ....... ....... ....</td>
    <td>And I want a blank line before this one.</td>
  </tr>
</tabel>
```

Comment: I don't understand how you're able to provide an answer to a question your don't understand

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. There are far, far better solutions that use semantic html and CSS.